# Redirects to a website do not complete

Tags: server, apache2, redirect

Ubantu 20.04 LTS
I have set up this server to replace a very old Mac OS server that will not serve a current version of TLS.
While I was using Apache on the Mac, the version on the Ubantu requires different configuration, and I have overcome much of my issues. I have a number of sites that are running properly and a number of redirects that take the user from ***.com to ###.com
I have site that I installed and configured and checked that is serving properly with https that I need to send a number of other sites to. I have set up the redirect on that site in a similar way to the ones that are working, yet I am not able to serve the proper site, they go to the default.
I have configured and reconfigured with what I thought was working settings and yet I cannot seem to get it to work.
This is the "target" conf file that is working:

> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName wescrap.ca
> ServerAlias [www.wescrap.ca](http://www.wescrap.ca)
> ServerAdmin webmaster@wescrap.ca   DocumentRoot /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html Redirect permanent /
> https://wescrap.ca
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html>
>     Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
>
> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wescrap.ca-error.log
> CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/-access.log combined </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> <VirtualHost *:443> ServerName wescrap.ca DocumentRoot
> /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html
>
> SSLEngine on SSLCertificateFile
> /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html/SSL/wescrap_ca.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile
> /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html/SSL/wescrap_ca.key
> SSLCertificateChainFile
> /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html/SSL/wescrap_ca.ca-bundle

This is the code for the redirect that is not:

> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName toronto-scrap.com
> ServerAlias [www.toronto-scrap.com](http://www.toronto-scrap.com) Redirect permanent / http://wescrap.ca/   DocumentRoot /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html

Would be most grateful for some suggestions as to a fix.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the record for `toronto-scrap.com`, I believe you're missing an `s`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName toronto-scrap.com
    ServerAlias www.toronto-scrap.com
    Redirect permanent / https://wescrap.ca/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wescrap.ca/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Redirect` was originally pointing to `http` rather than `https`.

Remember to reload Apache after making these changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: No joy on that. Same ending, goes to the default page for the server. I swap the DNS and check, then send it back the Mac server. This is a real puzzle!

Comment: Have you verified that the `.conf` file with this rule is enabled? Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo a2query -s`? This will show the virtual host files that are currently enabled.

Comment: It's not on that list! Will re-run the setup. Hopefully that will be the solution.

Comment: Just enable the file with `sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/999-toronto.conf` (change the file to what it actually is) and then restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Does the phrase "code blindness" work better than "how the heck did I miss that"? Thanks. It's always the step you thought you had taken that makes the difference when something goes wrong. Thank you again!